# How does SSL affect .NET Web Api security?

Tags: authentication, ssl, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I've read some about authentication and authorization inside of asp.net web api and I've understood that i basically must use ssl in order for not letting people get hold of the authentication tokens. And if i'm not misstaken theese authenticantokens are sent inside of the header? and SSL hides theese headers for the public not to to catch up if they use some tools for internet listening? If thats the case i guess i could create a "custom" authentication by not allowing the api to run unless a specific header is sent with the api call? Which people shouldn't be able to catch up if i use ssl?

I realized I've used alot of questionmarks but it is just to illustrate where my unclear thoughts are, any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication, Authorization and securing the connection over SSL are 3 different parts of a web application.

**Authentication**

Basically authentication handles *`who`* you are. For example with a login you provide a user and a password. The application knows now, who you are.

**Authorization**

Authorization manages the access rights for the user. It says, on *`what`* you have access. For example if you've provided the correct credentials, you are *`authenticated`*, but maybe not *`authorized`* for everything.

**SSL**

SSL is securing the connection like you said. You can't sniff (with WireShark or Fiddler) the network traffic if it's over `HTTPS`. This is a setting on your IIS on which the web api application is running. You don't need to create a "custom" authentication.

I hope this helps.